# Jquery/Ajax working in Safari but not Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox

This is a test page. There is a button that on click should load an entire external page extern2.php into the content div. Extern2.php works in both Safari and Firefox, however index.php only works in Safari.

The main page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Ajax Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.6.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function foo() {
         $('#content').load('extern2.php', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
  }
</script>

<meta name="robots" content="index, follow, noarchive" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
            {
       ?>

       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#content').load('extern2.php');
       });
       </script>

        <?
            }
        ?>

<div id="content">Initial content in test.html</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The external page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, noarchive" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

        <!-- This includes the ImageFlow CSS and JavaScript -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="imageflow.packed.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="imageflow.packed.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php 
    // Connecting to database
    $con = mysql_connect('CONNECT INFO HERE');
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("CONNECT INFO HERE", $con);
    $userID=2;

    $getPage="SELECT * FROM pages,thumbnails WHERE thumbnails.thumbnailID=pages.thumbnailID AND pages.userID=".$userID." AND pages.projectID='8' LIMIT 3";
    $pageResult = mysql_query($getPage) or die(" ". mysql_error());
    ?>

    <!-- This is all the XHTML ImageFlow needs -->
    <div id="myImageFlow" class="imageflow">
        <? while($line = mysql_fetch_array($pageResult)) {
            $thumb = $line['fileName'];
            $title = $line['title'];
            $link = $line['url'];

            echo "<img src='../../thumbnails/small/".$thumb."' longdesc='".$link."' alt='".$title."' />";  
        }
        ?>

    </div>

    <?
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the error console (CTRL-SHIFT-J) say?  Also does [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) help at all?

Comment: Could not read chrome manifest file '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/chrome.manifest'.

Comment: And snippets.mozilla.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555  thanks i will take a look and see what that means